# MarkLogic Optic API, existsJoin with data selection using empty qualifier resulting in 'Ambiguous column reference' error

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, marklogic-optic-api

I came across following situation - I use Optic API, I have first view filtered by second one using existsJoin to get only rowset I want. Then I need to include property which was used in op.on definition (the same column exists in both views) in objects which I return as a result, additionally that property must be present without any qualifiers etc.

Below is the simplest possible code that mimics what I need to do in mine application (using views created by TDE).

```
const op = require('/MarkLogic/optic');
const testViewToFilter = op.fromLiterals([
  {id:1000, val: 10},
  {id:1001, val: 11},
  {id:1002, val: 12}
], 'testViewToFilter');
const filteringView = op.fromLiterals([{id:1000}], 'filteringView')
testViewToFilter
  .existsJoin(
    filteringView,
    op.on(
      testViewToFilter.col('id'),
      filteringView.col('id')
    )
  )
  .select([testViewToFilter.col('id')], '')
  .result()
```

What I expect:

`[{id: 1000}]`

What I get:

```
[javascript] SQL-AMBCOLUMN: return plan.execute(query); -- Ambiguous column reference: found filteringView.id and id
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I achieve the result I expect?
I don't understand why do I get `Ambiguous column reference` for *id* column.

I get the same results for MarkLogic versions: `10.0-9.2` and `10.0-9.5`

Comment: Just want to comment on the quality of this post - great job providing an easily-reproduced issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the funny optic API nuances. Once a column has been used with a name more than once (even when using a qualifier), then in the future, you cannot create any column with the unqualified name.

If I have:
`foo.id`
and
`bar.id`
I cannot then create `id`

The error is the creation of `id` in the line   `.select([testViewToFilter.col('id')], '')`

You have two options:

1. A new qualifier:

   `.select([testViewToFilter.col('id')], 'filleMeIN')`

   Resulting in `{"filleMeIN.id": 1000}`
2. Redefine the column name:

   `.select([op.as("newId", testViewToFilter.col('id'))], '')`

   Resulting in `{"newId": 1000}`

Small note: this is language-independent. The same nuance exists when using xQuery

Comment: Thanks for the answer! During my investigation I noticed that changing qualifier in `.select()` makes it work but I didn't know that this is a nuance :)
How did you find out that this is the desired behavior and we have to overcome that by name change or new qualifier? Was something mentioned in the documentation? I didn't find anything regarding this in ML docs.

Comment: The Optic API documentation is sort of spread across the whole set of docs right now.  I have used  Optic API almost every day since its inception, so there are just some things I've absorbed. So no, I cannot remember if this is anywhere in the docs or not.